# Replacement for hal-get-property and hal-find-by-capability in udev?

Tags: linux, porting, udev, hal

I need to port a bash script which uses deprecated HAL tools like `hal-get-property` or `hal-find-by-capability` to udev. [HAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_%28software%29) states that HAL was merged into udev, but I couldn't find useful informations on how to proper port this script to udev.

Example:
If I want a list of all storage hardware (with HAL) I could run

`hal-find-by-capability --capability storage`

which would give me a list of UDI's (Unique Device Identifier) looking like that:

`/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/storage_model_Virtual_disk

/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/storage_serial_00000000000000000001

/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/platform_floppy_0_storage`

If I now want to find out if `/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/storage_model_Virtual_disk` is removable I could issue the following query

`hal-get-property --udi /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/storage_model_Virtual_disk --key storage.removable`

and it would answer `true` or `false`.

So my question is:
How can I do those things wihout HAL?
sysfsutils (`systool`) could work, but it doesn't seem to be a proper replacement.
Does this work with `udevadm info`?

Comment: is ``udevadm info --query=property`` what you're looking for, possibly in the form of ``udevadm info --query=property --name=$2`` and some other argument to select the device. As I don't have hal, I don't know what form the ``--udi`` argument takes, please tell us that.

Comment: I edited my original question. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, what you're up to do is way clearer. First, you have to find the devices you're about to query. The easiest way to do that, is actually scanning the sysfs. If you want to query a specific device, you just have to point udev to a location in the sysfs where the device is described. So if you're looking for `sdb`, you could for example go via `/block/sdb` or pick the correct node from `/dev/block` or anything like that. If you have your devices path, say `$DEVPATH`, you can do something like:

```
udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=$DEVPATH
```

This will spill out a lot of information, including the removability. Another set of information is shown if you replace `attribute-walk` with `query=property`, I was unable to find removability info there though.

If you want to do this for multiple devices, `find` and `xargs` will be your friends, which is basically your `hal-find-by-capability` replacement, as you just need to find the correct folder in sysfs.

---

Depending on what you're up to do, you might also want to read into [udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html), which allow you to trigger the execution of a script when a device is attached (by matching against the values given by `--attribute-walk`). You can also easily setup ownership and permissions and such things.